# Haskell type dessignation

Tags: haskell, types, type-conversion

I have to dessignate types of  2 functions(without using compiler :t) i just dont know how soudl i read these functions to make correct steps.

```
f x = map -1 x
f x = map (-1) x
```

Well i'm  a bit confuse how it will be parsed

Comment: `map -1 x` is parsed as `(map) - (1 x)`. But its type is not really nice.

Comment: doeas it mean we wanna minus something from map ?

Comment: Basically. This is going to put some crazy constrait on the function type (`Num (t -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b])`, I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function application, or "the empty space operator" has higher precedence than any operator symbol, so the first line parses as `f x = map - (1 x)`, which will most likely<sup>1</sup> be a type error.

The other example is parenthesized the way it looks, but note that `(-1)` desugars as `negate 1`. This is an exception from the normal rule, where operator sections like `(+1)` desugar as `(\x -> x + 1)`, so this will also likely<sup>1</sup> be a type error since `map` expects a function, not a number, as its first argument.

<sub><sup>1</sup> I say *likely* because it is technically possible to provide `Num` instances for functions which may allow this to type check.</sub>

Comment: It type checks for me, but the result is ugly.

Answer (score 3):

For questions like this, the definitive answer is to check the [Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/).  The relevant syntax hasn't changed from Haskell 98.

In particular, check the section on "Expressions".  That should explain how expressions are parsed, operator precedence, and the like.

Answer (score 2):

These functions do not have types, because they do not type check (you will get ridiculous type class constraints). To figure out why, you need to know that  `(-1)` has type `Num n => n`, and you need to read up on how a `-` is interpreted with or without parens before it.

The following function is the "correct" version of your function:

```
f x = map (subtract 1) x
```

You should be able to figure out the type of this function, if I say that:

```
subtract 1 :: Num n => n -> n
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Answer (score 0):

well i did it by my self :P

```
(map) - (1 x)
(-)::Num a => a->a->->a
1::Num b=> b
x::e
map::(c->d)->[c]->[d]
map::a
a\(c->d)->[c]->[d]
(1 x)::a
1::e->a
f::(Num ((c->d)->[c]->[d]),Num (e->(c->d)->[c]->[d])) => e->(c->d)->[c]->[d]
```